# String handling in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am trying to write a short python function to break a long one_line string into a multi_line string by inserting `\n`. the code works fine when i simply insert `\n` into the string but i get an index out of range error when i insert a conditional check to add hyphenation as well. Here is the code that i have written.

```
Sentence = "Python string comparison is performed using the characters in both strings. The characters in both strings are compared one by one. When different characters are found then their Unicode value is compared. The character with lower Unicode value is considered to be smaller."
for i in range(1, int(len(Sentence)/40)+1):
    x = i*40
    Sentence = Sentence[:x] + "\n" if Sentence[x] == " " else "-\n" + Sentence[x:]
print(Sentence)
```

Here is the error message i get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/u1/data/prop.py", line 4, in <module>
    Sentence = Sentence[:x] + "\n" if Sentence[x] == " " else "-\n" + Sentence[x:]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: `range` can take a step argument: `for x in range(40, len(Sentence), 40)`. That should be simpler than trying to manipulate the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional expression is greedy, parsed as if you had written

```
Sentence = Sentence[:x] + \
           ("\n" if Sentence[x] == " " else "-\n" + Sentence[x:])
```

As a result, you are doing one of two operations:

1. `Sentence[:x] + '\n'` if you find a space
2. `Sentence[:x] + "-\n" + Sentence[x:]` if you find a different character.

Note that case 1 *shortens* your sentence incorrectly, but your `range` object is based on the original correct list.

The solution is to use parentheses to define the conditional expression correctly:

```
for i in range(1, int(len(Sentence)/40)+1):
    x = i*40
    c = Sentence[x]
    Sentence = Sentence[:x] + (f"\n" if c == " " else f"{c}-\n") + Sentence[x+1:]
    #                         ^                                ^
```

Comment: This will fix the error, but I doubt the modified code will produce the desired results.

Comment: I think it would be parsed as `Sentence = (Sentence[:x] + "\n") if Sentence[x] == " " else ("-\n" + Sentence[x:])`? tested with `'3' + '5' if 0 else '99 + 7'` which return `'99 + 7'`

Comment: @SCKU I think you're right, because `+` is higher than `if-else` in the [Python operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really check the exact precedence, only that `Sentence` was getting *shorter* as the loop progressed. I think the main problem with the modified code is that it *replaces* `Sentence[x]` with `-"\n"` rather than inserting the hyphen *after* `Sentence[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue might not be obvious in the start but when you start looking at the `if` statement in the middle of string concatenation, you will understand. For a minute just focus on the following line:

```
Sentence = Sentence[:x] + "\n" if Sentence[x] == " " else "-\n" + Sentence[x:]
```

Python would parse this statement like so:

```
Sentence = (Sentence[:x] + "\n") if Sentence[x] == " " else ("-\n" + Sentence[x:])
```

Notice the brackets carefully. This is exactly the reason why the length of the string held by the variable `Sentence` is decreasing after each iteration which triggers the `IndexError` exception. Hence, in order to address this issue, we will have to explicitly tell Python what we are expecting. So, it could be written as such:

```
Sentence = Sentence[:x] + ("\n" if Sentence[x] == " " else "-\n") + Sentence[x:]
```

Comment: Why python doesn't parse statement like: `Sentence = (Sentence[:x] + "\n") if Sentence[x] == " " else ("-\n" + Sentence[x:])`?

Comment: @SCKU My bad. You are right. I'll edit it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "Python string comparison is performed using the characters in both strings. The characters in both strings are compared one by one. When different characters are found then their Unicode value is compared. The character with lower Unicode value is considered to be smaller."
stc = ""

for j in range(1 + len(string) // 40):
    stc += string[j * 40:40 * (j + 1)] + "\n"

print(stc)
```

Comment: I don't think this handles the `-` character though right?